# jQuery attr(). Changing the source on a block of images and the extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, attr

I am retrieving few images from an API and changing them to my own images as follows:

```
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/1.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/1.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/2.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/2.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/3.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/3.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/4.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/4.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/5.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/5.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/6.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/6.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/7.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/7.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/8.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/8.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/9.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/9.gif");
$('img[src="http://www.example.com/dir/images/dir/10.gif"]').attr('src', "http://cdn.example.com/dir/10.gif")
```

Now, because there's way too much text I compressed this as follows:

```
$('img[src^="http://www.example.com/"]').each(function(index,element){
  var $this, src, newSrc;
  $this = $(this);
  src = $this.attr('src');
  newSrc = src.replace('www.example.com/dir/images/dir', 'cdn.example.com/dir');
  $this.attr('src', newSrc);
});
```

Now, I want to change my images extension to `.png`. So basically I want to replace the URL for each images **AND the extension from `.gif` to `.png`**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZHUWD/ The solutions provided by either Darin or Tobias works fine.  You should include the rest of your code that surrounds that snippet above.  There is a good chance you are encountering scoping issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('img[src^="http://www.example.com/"]').attr('src', function() {
    return this.src
               .replace('www.example.com/dir/images/dir', 'cdn.example.com/dir')
               .replace('.gif', '.png');
});
```

Comment: It parses the original images

Comment: Sorry, had other issues in the code which made this not work. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
$('img[src^="http://www.example.com/"]').each(function(i, value) {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('www.example.com/dir/images/dir', 'cdn.example.com/dir').replace('.gif', '.png'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newSrc.replace(".gif",".png");
```

Think that will do the trick :)

Comment: What did you excatly do? 
newSrc = newSrc.replace(".gif",".png"); ?
It should work.